# C-Macro in if-Condition

Tags: c, macros

quite a simple problem I have here.

I have a little Macro for a global Variable which is defined in my Header like this:

```
extern bool uart_message_received;
#define get_uart_message_rec() uart_message_received;
```

In my C-File I want to access the file like this:

```
 bool uart_message_received = 0;
 void foo(void)
 {
       bool test;
       test = get_uart_message_rec();  // Works fine

       if(get_uart_message_rec()==0)    // Doesn't work
       {
          //...
       } 
 }
```

I am a little confused why the condition in the `if` is not working. Am I doing something wrong, or am I violating some C directives?

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? And, why are you using macros instead of functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define get_uart_message_rec() uart_message_received
                                                 // ^ no semicolon
```

Macro replacement will substitute the text as is, including the `;` in your case. Which will lead to syntax errors in the `if` case.

Comment: Ok, I could have really thought about that - thank you. - This means in my case when I write `test = get_uart_message_rec();` its practically `test = get_uart_message_rec();;` with double colon (which doesn't matter) .. ?

Comment: Exactly. And empty statements are allowed in C, so `;;` isn't an error.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the colon at the end of :

```
#define get_uart_message_rec() uart_message_received;
```

Because it becomes:

```
if(**uart_message_received;**==0)    // Doesn't work
{
    //...
}
```

When the preprocessor basically does find/replace on your code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon on the end of your macro - remove that, and it will be fine. Note that macros do replace exactly as written, so your macro expands from:

```
if(get_uart_message_rec()==0)
```

to:

```
if(uart_message_received; ==0)
```

which should make the compiler error.

[writing too slowly!]

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have a semicolon at the end of the macro.

Macros are replaced *as is*, before the actual compiler sees the text, so the statement after replacement looks like this:

```
if(uart_message_received;==0)
```