# Define macros with condition in C++

Tags: c++, c, macros, conditional-statements

I found some existing answer on SO, but I actually don't understand how does everything [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053975/c-macro-in-if-condition) works.

Basically, I want to define a macro in if/switch condition

```
if (condition)
{
#define SOME_MACRO
}
```

So, if some condition is true, there will be defined some new macro.
But, as for now, it just defines macro anyway. I understand that it's not really how it should be done, but there's no normal explanation to that.

Comment: [`#if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-if-hash-elif-hash-else-and-hash-endif-directives-c-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: No, the preprocessor happens at compile time, but `condition` is only known at run time.

Comment: @WeatherVane so, there's totally no way to do something like this?

Comment: @StupiStupiDu No, there's no way.

Comment: You should explain in a more general way what you want to achieve. Your example code should show what you want to do with the macro. Probably there is a different solution for your real problem.

Comment: @Bodo well, I explained everything in the answer of tarkmeper
It seems like there's no way, so...

Comment: @StupiStupiDu Of course I also read the comments to the answer. You explained that you want to define the macro based on keyboard input, which is not possible, but you didn't explain for what purpose you need the macro. So you only explained an idea for a solution you thought of, but not the whole problem or the use case.

Comment: @Bodo it's a pretty strange case but I wanted to make a cmd-like program which will get an int-input from user. Depending on input, there will be different parts of program which will run. For example, you type "1" and the program will run method for that input (let's say ```void divide()```). Then you type "2" and that will run ```void add()``` etc. Ah. It's a little sad that there's no real solution to that.

Comment: @StupiStupiDu ; Of course there is a solution to that; just not a solution using the pre-processor.  To be clear all the lines starting `#` are pre-processor directives, not part of the C language.  The pre-processor is used for conditional complication (including or excluding specific code sections) and defining macros - symbols and arguments that the pre-processor replaces with the definition text - _before_ the compiler itself parses the _result_ of the pre-processed source.  It is not a programming language and is not C code.  What you want to do can (and should) be done in C code.

Comment: This is an X-Y question.  You are are asking about an an impractical  solution you have devised, rather then simply asking about the problem you are trying to solve - which you have mentioned in a comment.  From the comment it seems like you do not understand the concept of a variable and are trying to use a macro as one.

Comment: _"[...] but there's no normal explanation to that."_ !?  What does that mean?  No normal explanation to what?

Comment: @StupiStupiDu For the problem mentioned in yourcomment you would simply call the different functions in a `switch`/`case` or `if`/`else` statement, e.g. `switch(input) { case 1: divide(); break; case 2: add(); break; default: error(); }` Macros would be the solution If you wanted to completely remove the `divide` function under certain conditions or maybe have two different implementations of `divide()` depending on the processor you are compiling for.

Comment: @Clifford I know that I can do that with very simple C code. However, I just forgot that macros are just preprocessor-thing here. That's it, okay, I understood every of all your and other people words, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix macros and code like that.  Macros are all processed before your code is compiled, it is just a convenience feature to save typing (and make code easier to read).

There is a macro syntax for conditions for example, you can do:

```
#if Condition
#define X
#endif
```

to conditionally define a macro.

Comment: What if there's an input from keyboard which return integer. So, integer is inside code. How can I use a condition
```#if x == 1
#define MACRO
#endif```
? Is it okay to do thing like this?

Comment: Also in C++ you should generally try to avoid using macros.  Your sample link, for example, shows one of the common problems with them.  In C++ many of the things that can be achieved by macros can be done using templates, constexpr or other techniques.

Comment: No - what you are suggesting won't work.  What are you trying to do? For a macro to take effect the code has to be recompiled this can't happen on a keypress.

Comment: Hmm. I think I have to learn more about these.
Actually, this is just experiment, so I would better understand this language (after Java). Thank you, I think I understand what to do next